# Fetching data from firebase with React Class component is rendering twice and even more

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, components

I have been struggling to make this work but it not working.

this my code:

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react'
import { Button, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import Todo from './components/Todo';
import db from './firebase';
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import firebase from 'firebase';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos: [],
      input: ''
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    let tmp_todos = this.state.todos;
    db.collection('todos').orderBy('timestamp', 'desc').onSnapshot( snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach( doc => {
        tmp_todos.push(doc.data().text);
      });
      this.setState({
        todos: tmp_todos
      });
    })
  }

  setInput(value){
    this.setState({
      input: value
    })
  }

  submitTodo(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    db.collection('todos').add({
      text: this.state.input,
      timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    })

    this.setState({
      input: ''
    })
  }

  addTodo(todo){
    return [...this.state.todos, todo];
  }

  render(){

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello les proooo </h1>
        <form>
          <TextField value={this.state.input} onChange={ event => this.setInput(event.target.value)} id="standard-basic" label="✅ Type your todo here..." />
          <Button disabled={!this.state.input} type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={this.submitTodo.bind(this)}>Add Todo</Button>
        </form>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
          {
            this.state.todos.map( 
              todo => (
                <Todo text={todo} />
              )
            )
          }
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

When it's loaded for the first time everything is ok, but when I add a new todo from the form input it refreshes the list and duplicates some item more than twice. I am lost please can someone help me.
this  how the output looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever your callback gets called with data from Firestore, the `snapshot` contains all data that exists at the location. So the first time it contains all initial todos, but then if you add one: you get called with all the previous ones, and the new one.

So you code will have to deal with that. You can either [determine the changes between the snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots), or (much simpler) you can clear the list of todo's whenever you get an update:

```
let tmp_todos = [];
db.collection('todos').orderBy('timestamp', 'desc').onSnapshot( snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach( doc => {
    tmp_todos.push(doc.data().text);
  });
  this.setState({
    todos: tmp_todos
  });
})
```

---

Or a bit simplified:

```
db.collection('todos').orderBy('timestamp', 'desc').onSnapshot( snapshot => {
  this.setState({
    todos: snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data().text)
  });
})
```

Comment: Thank you @FrankVanPuffelen, the second approach called the simplified version works perfectly. But, the first approach which I have to create the temp_todos to be an empty array didn't work I have tried this even before posting the question. Thank you once more